# Google Spreadsheet Protected Web-App Access Level Anyone

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth

I have deployed a gsheets web-app and the code executes fine if the web-app's "who has access to this" is set to "anyone, annonymous" access. below is this code.

```
  var data = {
    'command1': 'usermenu',
    'command2': 'dopayroll'
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : data
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(), options);  
  getSpread().toast(response.getContentText());
```

What I want to do, is change the access level to "Anyone" - which is access by any authenticated google account (right?). Added the following code to "var options" but returns an error code 401. How can I make this work?

```
  'header' : { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
```

EDIT; I should add that I'm a newbie in things related to OAuth and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a response posted which is now not visible.

My **thanks to the person** who did and having tested it, I can now confirm that the solution proposed works. There were 2 parts to the solution. First the correct header below ("header" should really be "headers")

```
'headers' : { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
```

and adding the following comment to trigger Drive scope access for the project.

```
// DriveApp.getFiles()
```